# if statement returning [[: not found

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, if-statement, scripting, sh

I'm writing a dinky little script and I need to do a check on values.

size is going to be a float, or number with decimal point for example like 28.0.

For some reason whenever I run, I get this error:

```
   while read -r line;
   do
           sample=$(echo $line | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"}; {print $5}')
           size=$(aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable $line | grep "Total Size:" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}; {print $3}')
   #       aws s3 cp $line ./crams/
           if [[ $( echo "${size} < 20" | bc ) -eq 1 ]]; then
                   echo "${sample}\t${size}"
           fi
   done < $1

download-aws.sh: 6: download-aws.sh: [[: not found
```

Any thoughts???

Also if you know of a better way to do the comparison of a float to a int... that'd be great!

Thanks

EDIT:

So I found a solution, I changed the if statement to:

```
if [ $( echo "${size} < 20" | bc ) -eq 1 ]; then
```

If anyone could point me in the direction of some awesome explanations of the logic behind the brackets etc... that'd be amazing!

Comment: What is the file that you are reading in?

Comment: Are you sure you're running Bash? That's the error you get when you run a shell that doesn't have the Bash-specific `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: Run `ps -p $$` or `echo $SHELL` to see the current shell. I bet it's not bash. And please remove the line numbers. See [Why is there no line numbering in code sections?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252559/995714)

Comment: @phuclv `$SHELL` is the user's default shell, not necessarily the shell that's actually in use, and running `ps -p $$` will show the shell that command was run from, not necessarily the one that's used for any particular script. Anyway, from the format of the error message, I'm pretty sure the script is being run under dash instead of bash. (And of course, dash doesn't support `[[ ]]` conditional expressions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "Bourne Shell built-ins" documentation:

> https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html
>
> ```
> test
> [
> test expr
> Evaluate a conditional expression expr and return a status of 0 (true) or 1 (false). Each operator and operand must be a separate
> ```
>
> argument. Expressions are composed of the primaries described below in
> Bash Conditional Expressions. test does not accept any options, nor
> does it accept and ignore an argument of -- as signifying the end of
> options.
>
> ```
> When the [ form is used, the last argument to the command must be a ].
> ```

In other words,

- `[` is an alias for "test"

Q: Is there any chance you could assign an integer to "size"?  So perhaps your test condition could simplify to something like:

```
if [ $size -lt 20 ]; then
 ...
fi
```

Comment: Unless you've previously verified that `size` is not empty and does not contain any characters in IFS, that should be quoted: `if [ "$size" -lt 20 ]`. Even if you have done the validation, the quotes should be used.